# Matching *ALL* items in a list with Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

So I have a Hibernate entity(lets call it Zoos) with a many-to-many relationship set up like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {})
@JoinTable(name = "animal",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "zoo_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "animal_id"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<Animal> getAnimal() {
    return animals;
}
```

So now I want to find all zoos with the animals "lions", "tigers", and "bears".  Now I don't care if they have other animals or not, but I don't want zoos with only tigers and marmosets.  What kind of criteria should I use given a list of animal names to match all elements of the list?  If I use Restricions.in I will get zoos that have at least one, but not necessarily all of the animals requested.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following query, that I'll let you translate to Criteria:

```
select zoo from Zoo zoo
where 3 = (select count(distinct animal.name) from Zoo zoo2 
           join zoo2.animals animal
           where zoo2.id = zoo.id
           and animal.name in ('lion', 'tiger', 'bear'))
```

Comment: I would also like the Criteria translation if that's readily available, thanks in advance.